# Filling specified regions in a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am creating a basic line plot with matplotlib. The x-axis represents percentiles. The y-axis represents time in seconds. I want to shade regions of a chart that represent each percentile (e.g, 0.25 and below, >0.25 and <= 0.5, etc.).

Here is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
from matplotlib import mlab
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import seaborn as sns

testx = np.array([0.0, 0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.9])
testy = np.array([0,5,14.75,40,96.1,120])

plt.plot(testx, testy)
plt.fill_between(testx, testy, where=(testx <= 0.25))
plt.fill_between(testx, testy, where=(testx > 0.25) & (testx <= 0.5))
```

This returns the following plot:

[image]

As can be seen, it properly shades the first fill_between where testx is less than or equal to 0.25. But it does not shade anything afterwards.

The expected output is to reproduce the shading multiple times for multiple ranges.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you call `fill_between` for a second time try wrapping your condition in another pair of brackets. I.e., `...where=((testx > 0.25) & (testx <= 0.5)))`

Comment: Thanks, FChm. This did not result in a proper fill, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, its because you don't have enough datapoints… i.e., `testx = np.array([0.0, 0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.9])` your fill_between condition only has one value which is `True` (where test_x=0.5). Try again with more dense sampling along x. (i.e., `test_x = np.linspace(0,1,100)` and your code will work.

Comment: This works! Thanks! But I don't know how to assign your comment as the answer.

Comment: There you go, i converted it to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you do not have enough datapoints.

I.e.,

```
testx = np.array([0.0, 0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.9])
```

This means that your condition:

```
where = ((testx > 0.25) & (testx <= 0.5))
```

has only one value equal to `True` (`where = [False False False True False]`) and `fill_between` has no where to fill between.

**You can address this by:**

a) Using denser 'x' sampling (i.e., test_x = `np.linspace(0,1,100)`)

b) Changing your condition to include values where x is equal to 0.25:

```
where = ((testx >= 0.25) & (testx <= 0.5))
```